# Change name of group "Custom toolbars" from "Add-ins" tab?

Tags: excel, ribbon, excel-2013, vba

I have a regular Excel file with some macro's and some simple buttons that I added through VBA. The buttons run certain macro's when clicked. The buttons can be found in the "Add-ins" tab, and are located in the "Custom toolbars" group. I would however like to change the name of that group to something else, like for example just "Buttons". 
I managed to figure out how to place the buttons to another group, called "Menu commands", but I can't seem to change the name of that group either (even though the name of the parent group of all the buttons is something completely different, it won't show up in the ribbon).
How do I do that? I've been searching endless and found no result so far. :(
I hope my question was clear, language might be a barrier here.

Thanks in advance for your help, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a little vague to give exact answer.  If your macro's are not truely add-ins and are specific to the workbook, you could create your own ribbon group and call it whatever you like and place it pretty much where you like, but how you do this depends on your office version.  Office 2007 would need to use some tool like CustomUI, but 2010 onwards, you may be able to do what you want via the UI, but need to be more specific about your requirements

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new Commandbar in VBA, it will be added to that group and you can't change the name of the group. If you create just buttons, they get added to the 'Menu commands' section - you can't rename that either. You need to look at using XML in the CustomUI part for better control - this is a good place to start: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section2.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the UI using the Ribbon XML markup which you can embedd into the Excel file. See [Load different RibbonX when opening file in Excel 2007 or 2010/2013](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win002.htm).

The Ribbon XML markup is described in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)